# Tools for turning RDB data into graph

Tags: graph, jena

I search about a simple and powerful tool to turn data in a relational database table into a graph, where it is possible to transverse this graph ( ex. by Breadth-first search method).
Any tools will be suggested please ?

Answer (score 0):

[This discussion](http://markmail.org/search/?q=jena-users#query:jena-users%20order%3Adate-backward+page:1+mid:hpdio6wdhxuam4a5+state:results) suggested:

- [D2RQ](http://d2rq.org)
- [VIVO-Harvester](https://github.com/vivo-project/VIVO-Harvester)
- [jena-csv](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/csv/) (for a CSV dump of the table)